# How to create Instance of google chrome in C#

Tags: c#, window

I want to create an object for google chrome and do like this.

```
dynamic browserId = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application.1");                       
        dynamic ie = Activator.CreateInstance(browserId);            
        ie.AddressBar = true;
        ie.MenuBar = false;
        ie.ToolBar = false;
        ie.StatusBar = false;
        ie.MenuBar = false;
        ie.Visible = true;
        ie.Navigate("www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Above code is working but I want to do same for google chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Open in default browser (Best Idea!) 
Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.net");

open in Internet Explorer
Process.Start("iexplore", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");

open in Firefox
Process.Start("firefox", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");

open in Google Chrome
Process.Start("chrome", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");

Comment: No, my intention is not that. I want to create an instance of google chrome in c# so I can handle interaction(events) between C# code and google chrome.